# SqlException:System.Data.SqlClient

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Windows Authentication for SQL Server failed for Visual Studio 2017 ASP.Net Core 2.0. I have an account `Asif\Sakib` in SQL Server Management Studio with Windows authentication.

Connection string:

```
Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=SalarydemoContext;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true
```

Worked for me before but now showing this problem:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>
> SqlException: Cannot open database "SalarydemoContext" requested by the login.
>   The login failed.
>   Login failed for user 'Asif\Sakib'.
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, object providerInfo, bool redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, bool applyTransientFaultHandling)

Comment: Well, the error pretty much says for itself. Try connecting to the server with some sql client under user Asif\Sakib.

Comment: but this user is present in the sql server management studio.